# handlebars not working in production after link click

Tags: javascript, jquery, handlebars.js, anchor, github-pages

I am using handlebars and it is working fine in development.  When I upload to github-pages, The handlebars template still works if i open directly to the page.  But if I go to a page in a link, the handlebars loop doesn't work.  Here is my code:

```
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../bower_components/handlebars/handlebars.min.js"></script>
</head>
<div id="content-placeholder"></div> 
<script id="some-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  {{#each this}}
    <div class=" col-md-4 col-sm-6 " data-animation-type="fadeIn" data-animation-delay="0.5s" data-animation-duration="2s">
       <div class="item-wrap">
          <figure class="">
             <div class="popup-call">
                <a href="assets/custom/images/blog/01.jpg" class="gallery-item"><i class="flaticon-arrows-4"></i></a>
             </div>
             <img src="{{this.picture.picture.url}}" class="img-responsive" style="height: 200px" alt="img11"/>
             <figcaption>
                <div class="post-header">
                   <h5><a href="blogpost.html">{{this.name}}</a></h5>
                </div>

             </figcaption>
          </figure>
       </div>
    </div>
  {{/each}}
</script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      var source   = $("#some-template").html();
      var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
      $.getJSON('https://my-url.com/teams.json', function(data){
        console.log(data);
        $("#content-placeholder").html(template(data));
      });
    });

</script>
```

I've tried doing it without the `document.ready()` but that doesn't change anything.

Comment: What is in your javascript console?

Comment: I'm guessing Handlebars isn't loading because the URL is changed.   Include how you are loading it in the page header.

Comment: There is nothing in the javascript console

Comment: @BretWeinraub i just added how i am loading handlebars

Comment: Open the page via link (which is the defect, right?) in Chrome, open dev tools (right click inspect) then look at the network tab.  Can you see the handlebars.min.js loaded there?  Refresh the page, can you see it now?  Are you sure there are no errors listed in the console (via link method) ??  OOps. I just now saw your stack score.. I suspect you already know this stuff?

Answer (score 0):

It's fairly clear that the handlebars.js isn't loading, because of the relative path in the script tag:

```html
 <script src="../bower_components/handlebars/handlebars.min.js"></script>
```

Replace src="" with your favorite CDN location:

For example

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.6/handlebars.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Handlebars works with Github pages. At least mine does not.